# Multiple document uploads to Wagtail Page

Tags: document, wagtail

Hi I am new to Wagtail and wondered if there is a simple way of adding multiple downloads to a single page type. I have created a custom page type and would like to be able to add several documents/downloads.  I have managed to get one to show, but can find no way of this being extended to add many.

```
downloads = models.ForeignKey('wagtaildocs.Document', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    DocumentChooserPanel('downloads'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a child model associated with your page model, via a `ParentalKey` and an `InlinePanel`. The tutorial at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#images gives an example of this - your setup is very similar, with the only real difference being that you're linking documents to the page rather than images:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    ...
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('documents', label="Documents")
    ]

class MyPageDocumentLink(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(MyPage, related_name='documents')
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        DocumentChooserPanel('document'),
    ]
```

Comment: Brilliant - works like a charm, thank you very much. I am not sure if I have enough rep to accept though :(.

Comment: Glad it works! (I'm pretty sure accepting answers on your own questions is always possible regardless of rep...)

Comment: Ah - there we go, I thought there would be a big "Accept" button rather than the tick.